# Does the choice of rating scale affect the average percentage score?

Tags: reference-request, behavioral-economics

Are there any differences in average percentage score when people are asked to judge things on different scales? Like for example rating something on 0/100 scale or a 0/5 scale or 0/10. Do different choices of scale introduce or remove biases?

5/5 = 100/100 but if someone told you they got 100/100 you would be more impressed. I think it is completely right that you would be as more important and more intensive testing uses 100/100 over 5/5 scaling, I know this from experience. These two are at two different extremes of the spectrum. What about say 10/10 or 20/20? If you got a group of people to rate something on these two scales would one score higher than the other on average?

I wonder if there are any studies about this (there probably are).
I have done a few searches but cannot find what I am looking for.

Comment: There's a famous [anecdote from Richard Thaler](https://www.chicagobooth.edu/review/the-evolution-of-economics-and-homo-economicus) that students react differently to average scores of 76/100 vs 96/137. Though the latter score is lower than the former in percentage terms, students made fewer complaints to the latter.